# How to fix "ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column" while inserting in multilevel nested table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types, object-relational-model, ordbms

Below is the Table/Object type Creation Query. Tables are created successfully

```
CREATE TYPE ft_obj AS OBJECT (
    ftid         NUMBER(5),
    ftlocation   VARCHAR(30),
    country      VARCHAR(10)
);
/

CREATE TABLE ft_table OF ft_obj (
    ftid PRIMARY KEY
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY;
/

CREATE TYPE frod_obj AS OBJECT (
    prodid           NUMBER(6),
    ft_ref           ft_obj,
    proddesc         VARCHAR(50),
    costperitem      DECIMAL,
    labcostperitem   DECIMAL
);
/

CREATE TABLE frod_table OF frod_obj (
    prodid PRIMARY KEY
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY;

CREATE TYPE wf_obj AS OBJECT (
    wfid           NUMBER,
    ft_ref         ft_obj,
    wfname         VARCHAR(30),
    taxcode        INT,
    yearlyincome   DECIMAL,
    yearlytax      DECIMAL
);
/

CREATE TABLE wf_table OF wf_obj (
    wfid PRIMARY KEY
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY;
/

CREATE TYPE wfusage_obj AS OBJECT (
    jobdate         DATE,
    jobhours        INT,
    jobhourlyrate   DECIMAL,
    jobposted       CHAR,
    wfid_ref        REF wf_obj
);
/

CREATE TYPE wfusage_nesttabtyp AS
    TABLE OF wfusage_obj;
/

CREATE TABLE wfusage_objtab OF wfusage_obj;
/

CREATE TYPE odetails_obj AS OBJECT (
    mfid           NUMBER,
    prodid_ref     REF frod_obj,
    quantity       INT,
    itemprice      DECIMAL,
    wfusage_ntab   wfusage_nesttabtyp
);
/

CREATE TYPE odetails_nesttabtyp AS
    TABLE OF odetails_obj;
/

CREATE TYPE prod_obj AS OBJECT (
    prodoid          NUMBER,
    odate            DATE,
    promisedate      DATE,
    completiondate   DATE,
    shipmentdate     DATE,
    status           VARCHAR(20),
    odetails_ntab    odetails_nesttabtyp
);
/

CREATE TABLE prod_objtab OF prod_obj (
    PRIMARY KEY ( prodoid )
) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY
NESTED TABLE odetails_ntab STORE AS oprod_ntab ( (
    PRIMARY KEY ( nested_table_id,
                  mfid )
)
ORGANIZATION INDEX
COMPRESS 
NESTED TABLE wfusage_ntab STORE AS wforder_ntab
)
RETURN AS LOCATOR
/

ALTER TABLE oprod_ntab ADD (
    SCOPE FOR ( prodid_ref ) IS frod_table
);
/
```

While inserting Data in the nested table getting the Error ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column. Below is the insert Query

```
INSERT INTO prod_objtab VALUES (
 46000,
 '25-April-2019',
 '12-May-2019',
 '13-May-2019',
  '13-May-2019',
  'COMPLETED',
  odetails_nesttabtyp(
      odetails_obj(46001
                    ,(SELECT REF(pt) 
                          FROM frod_table pt
                          WHERE pt.prodid = 10002)
                    ,100
                    ,400
                   ,wfusage_nesttabtyp(
                     wfusage_obj('25-April-2019'
                              ,60
                              ,100
                              ,'AME',
                             (SELECT REF(wf) 
                              FROM wf_table wf
                              WHERE wf.wfid = 252)
                    )
                )
              ) 
            )
          )
```

getting the error in line 9

> ORA-01401: inserted value too large for column

Answer (score 1):

Having spent over an hour debugging this I feel at liberty to say, what a horrible data model. Nested objects like this exemplify the inherent problems of OO as a method for managing data.

Anyway, the problem is this (inevitably the last thing I looked at):

```
  wfusage_obj('25-April-2019'
                          ,60
                          ,100
                          ,'AME', <------------ culprit
                         (SELECT REF(wf) 
                          FROM wf_table wf
                          WHERE wf.wfid = 252)
                )
```

`'AME'` is three characters long. This is populating `wfusage_obj.jobposted`, which you have defined as CHAR. Legitimate syntax but if we don't specify the data length it defaults to CHAR(1). Obviously this is two characters short for `'AME'`. It needs to be (at least) CHAR(3).

Once you've fixed this you will trip over

> ORA-22979: cannot INSERT object view REF or user-defined REF

This is because you have defined your tables with OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY. Consequently you can't use a REF on those tables. So, you need to remove that from the table definitions to make your code work.

I have posted [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73d0d4507e88cbdf74e8bf5bab177a7b0)